# Is SonarLint 3.2.0 compatible with sonarqube 6.2?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I am trying to connect to a remote sonarqube 6.2 server from Sonarlint 3.2 plugin in eclipse neon. I am able to connect to my local server http://localhost:9000.

But When I am trying to hit the remote sonar server I am getting below error:

> Fail to request https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxx/xxx/api/system/status

Please advise.

Comment: "The connected mode is compatible with SonarQube 5.6+." You are going to have to investigate further, starting with basic net and HTTP comms between the respective hosts.

Comment: Formatted quote

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself using SonarLint 3.1 and SonarQube 6.7.

In IntelliJ I kept running into this error message

```
Failed to connect to the server. Please check the configuration.
Error: Fail to request https://<SONARQUBE>/api/system/status
```

However I could access that URL through my browser without any issues.

When you WireShark the requests coming from the browser and the IDE you can see that the cypher suite is quite different and that the IDE plugin gets a TLS handshake failure.

That lead me to discover that Java still ships with limited strength cryptographic functions. That’s either because of US export policy or because  nobody has gotten around to fixing it. The internet isn’t quite sure.

Either way, you can download the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Once I installed those onto the IntelliJ JVM, I no longer got the underlying TLS handshake failure when trying to connect to SonarQube and the connection works.